# SceneKit Particles and blend mode

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

I have a scene into I which I load particles for specific events. I borrowed some of the particle effects from the Apple fox2 demo as a start and they seem to work fine, but only the first time it's added to the scene. The second time the particles are fired the blend mode on the particle textures seems to be broken. I can see the black background of the image. It's a simple black and white image, but even if I convert all the black to transparent pixels it behaves the same way.

I've tried setting the blend mode programatically, but it makes no difference. The first time is ok, the second time it's ugly. Does anyone have anythign I can try?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since Metal images used for particles need to be greyscale with alpha channels. Apple's fox example project uses black and white images and that no longer works. So I had to convert all the particle mask images to get the blend mode to work appropriately.